# Issues with Spring Initializr project in IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, spring-initializr

I created a project using Spring Initializr.

When I open it in IntelliJ I see this error in the build:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:
>
> 1. Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.maven.model.validation.DefaultModelValidator: method 'void ()' not found
>    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.embedder.CustomModelValidator.(Unknown Source)
>    while locating org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.embedder.CustomModelValidator
>    at ClassRealm[maven.ext, parent: ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
>    while locating org.apache.maven.model.validation.ModelValidator annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value="ide")
>
> 1 error
> role: org.apache.maven.model.validation.ModelValidator
> roleHint: ide

I also noticed if I try to add a run configuration no main class is found. What could be wrong here?

Comment: First try to build your project on plain command line not inside any IDE....

Comment: @khmarbaise I have the same issue, builds fine in terminal, reimport fails again with the same error

Comment: Which version of intellij do you use?

Answer (score 5):

Tried

> ./mvnw spring-boot:run

and it worked fine but running it in IDE fails. IntelliJ by default uses the Maven wrapper to load the project.

Therefore there are two temporary solutions:

- Navigate to settings > build tools > maven and use a different maven home
  path (use a locally installed maven or bundled version)
  [image]
- Delete the mvnw file so it will force Idea to use locally installed maven